# Kohana Auth Custom Driver, model user?

Tags: authentication, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm, kohana-auth

I have made a custom driver 'Auth_MyDriver' that extends Auth

I looked here how to: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/auth/driver/develop

And did so that when using this driver, it grab/logins the user from "`test_users`" instead of "`users`"

Now, when I use the custom driver "`MyDriver`" the `Auth::instance()->get_user()` it returns a string with the `username`.

When I use the default "`orm`" auth driver and call `Auth::instance()->get_user()` it returns a whole object with the user data all grabbed from the users table, so you are able to call e.g `Auth::instance()->get_user()->email`

How can I make my custom driver work like the default orm auth driver, except that it should just look for test_* tables instead (test_users, test_roles, test_roles_users)

I spent hours on trying to find out, and I think its something about a Model User, that I need for my custom driver in order to do this ?

Hope for any help thanks!

Update:

My MyDriver, has the same method as the Auth File driver

```
public function get_user($default = NULL)
{
    return $this->_session->get($this->_config['session_key'], $default);
}
```

Comment: Did you alter the `get_user` method in your driver and/or the use of sessions?

Comment: @kingkero check my update, my custom driver use the same get_user() as the file driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally:

I simply grabbed the user from the database, turned into an object and send with complete_login:

```
$user = DB::select()->from($table_name)
->where('username', '=', $username)
->as_object()->execute()->current();

if(!empty($user))
{
    if($password == $user->password)
    {
        return $this->complete_login($user);
    }
}
```

This will do it :-)